# Use of an IDE when my server is on a VM

Tags: macos, ide, virtual-machine

I mostly develop in PHP, but I'm using Python and Ruby more and more. I edit the code in my OS (I'm on a Mac, so OS X Snow Leopard), but my server is on a VM (VM Fusion).

I use the IDEs mostly for their syntax checking - something TextMate, Espresso, et al, are not so good at. However, I can see that all these IDEs have vastly more power than syntax checking, but I'm not using it because the server is a VM.

For example, being able to set breakpoints and step through code. I've used these features with JavaScript, so I know how useful they are, but I can't use them because my server is on a VM instead of running natively inside the same OS as the IDE.

Is there a way of taking advantage of all these powerful features, without either developing inside the VM or running the server in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what sort of server you have that couldn't be run natively in Mac OS X for development -- pretty much anything would work great. Alternatively, you can run the IDE in the VM along with the server -- desktop apps work just fine in VMWare too. So you have two excellent alternatives facing you -- do whichever one is easier!

Comment: It's only Apache, so it's not a technical limitation, more of a bad experience of integrating my development server so tightly inside my day-to-day OS. Using VMs keeps things nice and clean - I keep a working VM copy that I can set up within minutes. I don't really want to have a GUI VM (which I would need to run an IDE inside it) - it's only a Macbook Pro so it gets really slow doing that.

Comment: You could use a stripped-down server for development, maybe. Mac OS X comes with a copy of Apache all set up already, so maybe you could piggyback off of that.

Comment: If you have 4GB RAM in a MBP, a GUI VM works very nicely, in my experience.

Comment: OK, I will give both a go. I was hoping that there would be some way of having an independent fake server within the IDE but I can't find a way of doing that.